# Visual Studio Code and emmet !important CSS modifier

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, emmet

I have problems with the use of `!` in my CSS code.

If I take the example in the Emmet documentation :

```
p!+m10e!
```

Should produce:

```
padding:  !important;
margin: 10em !important;
```

On my side, it doesn't work. `p!+m10e` works, but `p!+m10e!` does not. The final exclamation point seems to be a problem.

I did another test with `dn!` to display `display: none !important;`, the problem is the same.

[image]

Do you have an idea?

Comment: It works fine for me

Comment: You need to make sure that your typing it in brackets though. Also, if somthing like this doesn't work, always try disabling all extensions. You can disable them via the VSCode CLI very eaily. Also clear your browser history, and make sure your CSS Emmet & snippets files are restored to their default state (or just empty). If you have something in them u don't want to delete, temporarily save the files to  another location until you have finished troubleshooting the issue. If none of this works, open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Try after installing `Mithril Emmet`  extension in vs code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution lies in disabling `text-suggestions`. In fact, I think the fact that IntelliSense shows the `!important` and `!default`
when you type an exclamation mark, makes Emmet mess up.

So I disabled this:

```
"editor.suggest.showWords": false
```

If you prefer the UI, you can also find it by doing the following:

1. Navigate the menus: click on - File > Preferences > Settings (or
   press Ctrl + ,)
2. Type Show Words in the search box at the top
3. Uncheck the setting Editor > Suggest: Show Words

Answer (score 1):

Enabling `Trigger Expansion on Tab` seems to have solved the problem on my machine.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A few observations, this may help future readers:

- `CTRL + Space` forces the non-suggested(intellisense) expansion.
- `"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true` also expands non-suggested option.
- If you type `dn!i` it will give you suggestion `dn: i !important;` then you delete 'i' then hit enter/tab, it expands as expected.
  [image]
- I think the bug https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/120245 still hasn't been resolved completely. Otherwise you could've typed 'dn!important` and it would've expanded as expected.